# present perfect in relative clauses introduced by simple present

Tags: present-perfect, relative-clauses

May I have your opinion on the following? I have been asked if this sentence should be:

> "this is the report I prepared"  or 
>   "this is the report I have prepared".

I would opt for the first version, my reasoning being that the audience supposedly know already about the document, otherwise why introduce it with "this is / here is the ...". That being the case, there is no need to use the present perfect, although the sentence on the whole is probably acceptable, as the situational context would have been be the start of a meeting. The speaker surely wanted to highlight the relevance of his work to the event about to begin.

However, a different article, as in 
"this is **a** report I prepared/ have prepared"
would for me tip the balance in favour of the present perfect.

On the whole, I am now inclined to think that both pres. perf. and simple past could be acceptable in the original instance of the sentence. My judgement was probably skewed against the present perfect due to the student's placing undue emphasis on it in pronunciation (as in: "this is the report I HAVE prepared)

What say you?

Comment: I think the simple past focuses more on the result while the present perfect focuses on the action of *preparing*

Comment: Actually, based on some rules of thumb usually given to learners, the simple past is reserved for events located in a finished period of time, while the present perfect is for events that have taken place at an unspecified point in the past or have relevance to the present. Another rule of thumb is that news are cast in the present perfect. But the point is, rules for learners are often contradicted by usage, and by speakers' individual assessment of the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that the article choice makes too much of an impact on meaning to help judge which is correct here. "The" implies that it is one that they should know of, that they had spoken of before. "A" implies that this is new material, one you might not know specifically about.

That said, I can't parse and figure out why info that you're reminding a person of should be expressed differently than info you are presenting anew. Perhaps "I prepared" attaches to the object more strongly than "I have prepared", which sounds like context instead of identification.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Very interesting what you have to say about the present perfect feeling like context, additional information, as opposed to "I prepared", which attaches to the object more strongly, in this way demanding, so to speak, less attention. Supposing I am not misunderstanding your meaning, I think this is what I was trying to articulate, and confirm. The two types of past have a different "weight" and it can be down to personal preference whether to use one or the other. The periphrastic tense weighs down the subordinate clause.

Comment: As for _why info that you're reminding a person of should be expressed differently than info you are presenting anew_: 1. "I've meanwhile collected some data that I'd like to share with you now..." -- informing the audience of the existence of the document, no details as to the how, when, etc. 2."The data were obtained both researching our archives and ..." --  moving on to the details, the tense shifts to simple past. Don't you agree that news tends to be given in the present perfect tense?